# Cypress If/Else condition in Cucumber

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using Cucumber for testing a bank application where I can open a Checking and a Savings account based on the value in the dropdown.
Sample code :

```
When("Savings account")
    cy.get('#type').select('SAVINGS')
When("Checking account")
    cy.get('#type').select('CHECKING')

Then("Account is created")
    cy.get('#accountType').should('have.text', 'CHECKING') or 
    cy.get('#accountType').should('have.text', 'SAVINGS')
    based on what is selected in the When statement.
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `should(callback)` for checking the text when criteria is more complicated.

Using `should()` gives you retry and is preferred over `.then()`.

```js
cy.get('#accountType')
  .should($el => {
    const text = $el.text().toUpperCase()          // make sure case matches
    expect(['CHECKING', 'SAVINGS']).to.include(text)   
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `to.be.oneOf` assertion for this.

```js
cy.get('#accountType')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('not.be.empty')
  .then((text) => {
    expect(text).to.be.oneOf(['CHECKING', 'SAVINGS'])
  })
```

Comment: I get error for this : `assertexpected '' to be one of [ CHECKING, SAVINGS ]`

Comment: This means that `.invoke('text')` is not able to retrieve the inner text of the element. Updated the answer to retry till the text is available.